# Can Flash Remoting run through a HTTP (Squid) proxy server

Tags: flash, remoting, reverse-proxy, squid

I have a network were would like like to deliver data using the Flash Remoting data format over HTTP.  We have Squid working as a reverse proxy/accelerator, are there any known problems running this traffic through Squid.  We would configure that particular URL to not be cached.

Answer (score 0):

If Squid is not caching that URL or modifying the request or response, I think it's unlikely to cause any problems. That's the point, right? That's a big if though...

Just be glad that you control the Squid. That way, if there is a problem, you can change the configuration relatively quickly. Relying on an externally controlled squid to not snarf up your application would be a potential point of failure.